# How can i change the field name based on condition in xml file?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8, openerp-8

How can I change the field name based on condition in XML file?

My code is:

```
<field name="parent_id" position="attributes">    
    <attribute name="string">{'HOD':[('is_student','=',True)]}</attribute>    
</field>
```

If field *is_student* is True, then Show *HOD* otherwise keep as *Manager* only.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am not able to do in XML file, because if I try the @Odedra solution, my design getting disturbed.

I'm achieve it with this code:

```
def fields_get(self, cr, uid, fields=None, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context={}
    res = super(hr_employee, self).fields_get(cr, uid, fields, context)
    if 'parent_id' in res and 'is_student' in context and context['is_student']:
        if 'string' in res['parent_id']:
            res['parent_id']['string'] = 'HOD'
    return res
```

Comment: Don't forget to pass field *is_student* in context. Otherwise you didn't get the real time value of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

Replace below code

```
<field name="parent_id" position="attributes">    
    <attribute name="string">{'HOD':[('is_student','=',True)]}</attribute>    
</field>
```

with

```
<field name="parent_id" position="replace">
    <div>
        <label for="parent_id" attrs="{'invisible': ['is_student','=',False)]}">
        <label for="parent_id" string="HOD" attrs="{'invisible': ['is_student','=',True)]}">
        <field name="parent_id">
    </div>
</field>
```

Comment: Same thing i expected, thanks .
Change the attrs , because is_student is True, i want to show HOD only

Comment: As <div> tag disturbing my design i tried

<field name="parent_id" position="replace">
   <label for="parent_id" attrs="{'invisible':[('is_student','=',True)]}"/>
   <label for="parent_id" string="HOD" attrs="{'invisible':[('is_student','=',False)]}"/>
   <field name="parent_id" nolabel="1"/>
  </field>

Comment: But, still my design getting disturbed